# How to don't save null parameter in table if got parameter with null field in Django

Tags: django, database, orm, model, null

I have table with some parameters like this:

```
class Education(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(default=None)
```

In Django request from client maybe `content` field equals to **NULL**. So i want to when `content` parameter is NULL Django does not save it in database but does not show any errors.
Maybe already this field has data and in the **Update** request client just want to change `title` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, Just like this:

```
class EducationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Education
        fields = ['title', 'content')
        extra_kwargs = {'content': {'required': False}}
```

Comment: No, you need to set: `extra_kwargs = {'content': {'required': False}}`

Answer (score 1):

In your form / serializer sets the `content` field as not required, so if the client doesn't want to update that field, it simply doesn't pass a value.

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Education


class EducationForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = Education
      fields = ('title', 'content')

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['content'].required = False
```